# How to generalize the Diffie-Hellman key exchange to three or more parties?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I know how to do a key exchange between 2 parties, but I need to be able to have a key agreement between 3 or more parties.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on [CS.SE].

Comment: There is a way, but why complicate things? Just do key exchange between A and B, and separately between A and C, and then have A give an encrypted key to B and C.

Comment: Alice computes ga and sends it to Bob.
.Bob computes (ga)b = gab and sends it to Carol.
Carol computes (gab)c = gabc and uses it as her secret.
 something like this??

Comment: @sabamushtaq Right. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be a bit more complex than two.

Consider a loop with *N* people. Each is numbered 1, 2, 3, ..., *N*. They share the same *P* and *G*. Everyone has his own *a<sub>i</sub>* number. Now everyone computes *G<sup>a</sup>* for themselves, and send the result to the next one. Then everyone computes the value *G<sub>1</sub><sup>a</sup>* where *G<sub>1</sub>* is the value that the previous person gives. Repeat the procedure for *N* times and everyone has the same number *G<sub>N</sub>* = *G<sup>a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>N</sub></sup>*.

Pseudocode:

```
import G, P from public
generate a
send pair{pow(G, a, P), 1} to next person
for i = 1 to N-1:
  receive pair{Gx, x} from previous person
  if x = N:
    key = Gx
  else
    send pair{pow(Gx, a, P), x+1} to next person
return key
```

Comment: Why can't you just send your key to all the other participants and receive keys from them too, then perform pow operation on them? I mean it would be so much simpler.  Are there any issues with that?

Comment: @MarkVirchenko The key point is that everyone keeps their `a` secret while trying to figure out a common key. Also note that it's impractical to calculate `G^ab` using only `G^a` and `G^b`, so "broadcasting" doesn't work here.